# Why popup does not closing after entering email and password. Facebook API. JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, electron

I have this code:

```
// Require file system
const fs = require('fs')

// Require PORT and HOST from 'config-server.json'
const { PORT, HOST } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./api/config-server.json', 'utf-8'))

// Require client_id, client_secret for init
const { clientId, clientSecret } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json', 'utf-8'))

// Init function
init = (clientId, cb) => {
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId       : clientId,
      xfbml       : true,
      status      : true,
      version     : 'v2.8',
      oauth       : true
    })
    cb()
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     const fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return
     const scriptElement = d.createElement(s)
     scriptElement.id = id
     scriptElement.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, fjs)
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))
}

// Login function
const login = () => {
  FB.getLoginStatus((res) => {
    if (res.status === 'connected') {
      FB.api('/me', { fields: 'last_name' }, (res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
    } else {
      console.log('Login...')
      const btnLogin = document.getElementById('login')
      btnLogin.onclick = () => {
        FB.login(res => {
          // Reload after close popup
          window.location.reload(true)
        })
      }
    }
  })
}

init(clientId, () => {
  // Call login() after init()
  login()
})

const btnLogout = document.getElementById('logout')
btnLogout.onclick = () => {
  if (FB.getAccessToken()) {
    // Logout if someone logged in
    FB.logout()
    window.location = 'http://localhost:1488'
  } else {
    console.log('Already logged out')
  }
}
```

I have two buttons. For login and logout. When user click on login button, he see popup with fields for email and password. I am entering email and password. And then i see just white and empty window. And if i close him, then i reload my page and user is logged in. But why this popup does not close himself after entering email and password?

`window.location` of empty popup: `https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FiPrOY23SGAp.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df2e4d3b22b23a58%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A1488%252Ff1ab14344773ff%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df3fb6c65fd4473c&display=popup&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&domain=localhost&origin=1&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ret=login&sdk=joey&logger_id=4cadbeee-9751-448a-86bc-96662e65a50a&ext=1482371052&hash=AeYNXe5MCMhq1eZX`

## Screenshots:

[image: Enter email and password]

[image: Then i see this popup]

[image: And if i closed this popup i get info about user]

Comment: "white and empty window" means you can open the browser console in that window and check for errors.

Comment: @luschn no errors. Clear window. without any elements and `window.location` equal `"https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FiPrOY23SGAp.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df2e4d3b22b23a58%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A1488%252Ff1ab14344773ff%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df3fb6c65fd4473c&display=popup&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&domain=localhost&origin=1&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ret=login&sdk=joey&logger_id=4cadbeee-9751-448a-86bc-96662e65a50a&ext=1482371052&hash=AeYNXe5MCMhq1eZX"`

Comment: did you open the browser dev tools and check out the console? in that popup?

Comment: (press F12 while the window is focused)

Comment: @luschn added screenshots. check

Comment: waaait a minute...is that code server side? the "fs" module is a node.js module. but you are trying to use the client javascript sdk on your node.js server, am i right?

Comment: you need to use it client side, for example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: it's a Electron. I can use node.js module on client side

Comment: @luschn it's a client side

Comment: i understand. i don´t have a lot of experience with electron though, i´m afraid. the redirect_uri in FB.init is weird though. you don´t need to specify a redirect_uri when using the js sdk.

Comment: that parameter does not even exist: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.8

Comment: @luschn got it. and remove this line. but problem still exist

Comment: `window.location = 'http://localhost:1488'` - is that the actual address you got this whole thing running under? In my experience, FB login does not work well with non-standard posts. I strongly recommend that you set up a local domain name for testing (something like `myapp.local`), and use the standard HTTP ports (80/443) - that causes the least problems.